# Print column and row name of cell if cell in table is greater than 0 using python pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, html-table

I am having trouble to retrive name of column and row of cell in a table

my scenario is-
if any element in my table is greater than 0
then print its column and rows name

example
i have attached a photo of my table
i need to print date and slot time of cell if any cell is greater than 0

response i would expect is below from table i attached

```
08-05-2022 , SLOT1(07.30-08.00)  
08-05-2022 , SLOT2(11.00-11.30)
08-05-2022 , SLOT3(14.00-14.30)
08-05-2022 , SLOT4(15.00-15.30)
09-05-2022 , SLOT1(07.30-08.00)
09-05-2022 , SLOT4(15.00-15.30)
10-05-2022 , SLOT3(14.00-14.30)
11-05-2022 , SLOT2(11.00-11.30)
```

[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXk9V.png)

this code used by me to filter columns having cell greater than 0
from a big table
image i attached is filtered using below code
i cannot find any code to solve my issue i described above

```
filtered = df.loc[df['SLOT1 (07.30-08.00)'] != 0]
print (filtered)
filtered2 = filtered2.loc[df['SLOT2 (11.00-11.30)'] != 0]
print(filtered2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stack the columns first, then loop through each row and print rows that meet the requirement:

```
# creating similar dataframe
cols = ["slot1", "slot2", "slot3", "slot4", "slot5", "slot6", "slot7", "slot8"]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 5, (4, 8)), columns=cols)
df["date"] = pd.date_range("2022-05-01", periods=4, freq="D")
df["day"] = ["MON", "TUES", "WED", "THURS"]
df = df[["date", "day"] + cols]

# loop through rows of stacked dataframe
for idx, i in df.set_index(["date", "day"]).stack().iteritems():
    if i > 0:
        print(idx)
#(Timestamp('2022-05-01 00:00:00'), 'MON', 'slot1')
#(Timestamp('2022-05-01 00:00:00'), 'MON', 'slot2')
#(Timestamp('2022-05-01 00:00:00'), 'MON', 'slot3')
#(Timestamp('2022-05-01 00:00:00'), 'MON', 'slot6')
#(Timestamp('2022-05-01 00:00:00'), 'MON', 'slot7')
#(Timestamp('2022-05-01 00:00:00'), 'MON', 'slot8')
#(Timestamp('2022-05-02 00:00:00'), 'TUES', 'slot1')
#(Timestamp('2022-05-02 00:00:00'), 'TUES', 'slot2')
#(Timestamp('2022-05-02 00:00:00'), 'TUES', 'slot3')
#(Timestamp('2022-05-02 00:00:00'), 'TUES', 'slot5')
#(Timestamp('2022-05-02 00:00:00'), 'TUES', 'slot6')
#(Timestamp('2022-05-02 00:00:00'), 'TUES', 'slot7')
#(Timestamp('2022-05-02 00:00:00'), 'TUES', 'slot8')
#...
```

The index needs to be set to date and day first, so that each slot is still attributed to the given date.  Because that day is set as the index too, this will be in the output.  You could choose to drop this first, if you don't need it, or change the loop's print statement:

```
for idx, i in df.set_index(["date", "day"]).stack().iteritems():
    if i > 0:
        print(idx[0].strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), ",", idx[2])
```